# Xamarin.Forms WebAuthenticator and Google

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-authentication, xamarin.essentials

I have been trying now for a while to retrieve Google Calendar information from a google user in Xamarin.Forms.

I started my journey using Xamarin.Auth but I could not get past an issue where after a login the CustomTab in my Android App would not close. Seems to have been an ongoing problem for years now and several people proposed hacks to get around this problem. I gave up on Xamarin.Auth at this point

So I tried to use Xamarin.Forms [Web Authenticator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?tabs=ios) to retrieve the calendar information. The documentation does not mention how to authenticate with Google so I tried this

```
var authResult = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(
                new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"), // auth url
                new Uri("packageNameOfMyApp://");        // redirect url
```

I am getting an invalid request error

[image: screenshot]

How do I have to choose the first parameter of AuthenticateAsync to properly authenticate with Google?
Do I have to somehow encode the ClientId from my app I obtained after configuring my application login via the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com)?

Comment: Try to use `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth` as first parameter.

Comment: I am still getting the same error message (Error 400 invalid request)

Comment: Same is actually true if I hit this endpoint with my browser

Comment: The problem should be caused by the redirect url.

Comment: If I follow the Web Authenticator documentation, the redirect url should be the app name (I assume the package name listed in the manifest file) followed by ://  I tried changing this url around but still I am getting the same error. I implemented the WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity class as suggested in the documentation

Comment: Take a look at the information in this [thread](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1224#issuecomment-614418779).

Comment: So interpreting the last comment in the [thread](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1224#issuecomment-614418779), it is only theoretically possible to use WebAuthenticator if you don't have your own backend implemented. Is this correct?

Comment: No, I don't think so. A backend won't limit you to use WebAuthenticator.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: The solution is to not use the WebAuthenticator. Instead use the web browser to do the authentication for you. If you have setup your url scheme correctly, your app will be invoked by the browser and you can extract the token in your MainActivity or AppDelegate

Comment: any samples to put me in right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use WebAuthenticator with Google. Google requires a web browser to do the authentication and does not permit your app to authenticate by itself. For the same reason, an approach where you use WebView in your app to navigate to the Google authentication site will fail

Comment: atleast he got it working https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCPENg5wP8o did not work on my side . stuck on the redirect issue