# Using Xamarin Essentials WebAuthenticator to get Google Id_token

Tags: asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, google-signin, xamarin.essentials, webauthenticator

Im using the Xamarin Essentials as a part of a Xamarin Forms application i'm developing.
I have integrated it in to my aspnet.core backend, and it works fine.

However im getting an accesstoken returned when i sign in with google and facebook, but in case of the google login, i need the id_token and not the accesstoken.

I've looked at the 'AddJwtBearer' method on the 'AddAuthentication' part in startup, but i have not been able to make it work when i use the 'AuthenticateAsync' method in controller.

How would one accomplish this?
The backend is based on code from this sample:
https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/develop/Samples/Sample.Server.WebAuthenticator/Controllers/MobileAuthController.cs

Comment: Come on! Anyone?

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Comment: Hi @AmjadSaab. I'll test it out today when i get home - thanks for the suggestion. I'm pretty sure the idToken is not returned when using the AuthenticateAsync method, but i´ll check again.

Comment: sure plus note the Id token needed to be parsed maybe thats why u couldnt be able to access it\

Answer (score 2):

try to get it from here:

```
var auth = await Request.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(scheme);
var idtoken = auth.Properties.GetTokenValue("id_token");
```

or

```
 string refreshToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");
```

Check this class

```
 public class WebAuth
    {
        private const string AuthenticationUrl ="https://myapp.com/mobileauth/";

        private string _accessToken = "";
        private bool _isAuthenticated = false;

        public string AuthToken
        {
            get => _accessToken;
            set => SetProperty(ref _accessToken, value);
        }
    
       

        async Task OnAuthenticate(string scheme)
        {
            try
            {
                scheme = "Facebook";
                WebAuthenticatorResult result = null;

                var authUrl = new Uri(AuthenticationUrl + scheme);
                var callbackUrl = new Uri("myapp://");
                result = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(authUrl, callbackUrl);
                
                AuthToken = string.Empty;

                if (result.Properties.TryGetValue("name", out var name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                {
                    AuthToken += $"Name: {name}{Environment.NewLine}";
                }

                if (result.Properties.TryGetValue("email", out var email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
                {
                    AuthToken += $"Email: {email}{Environment.NewLine}";
                }
                
                AuthToken += result?.AccessToken ?? result?.IdToken;
                IsAuthenticated = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AuthToken = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didnt work - token is null

Comment: is it null before parsing it?

Comment: can you explain why do you need the idtoken

Comment: check please the class i edited

Comment: i find this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64953264/xamarin-forms-webauthenticator-and-google

Comment: To be clear - the WebAuth class is ment to be implemented on client right? If so - the client is not the issue, the backend is. All that is returned when calling 'AuthenticateAsync'  from controller is an access_token, but i need the id_token to sign in to mongodb realm sync on client. The authentication method seems to work as intended, but i need it to give me the id_token also. Perhaps i need to setup some middleware? It is based on the git sample found here: https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/develop/Samples/Sample.Server.WebAuthenticator/Controllers/MobileAuthController.cs

Comment: yes you r right you need to enable some properties in the authenticator side related to the return claims eg. idtoken

Comment: did you enable JWT token in the authenticator server?

Comment: Tried but i dont know how - got a bunch of errors when i tried to add the middleware

Comment: what type is your authenticator ?

Comment: I'm a bit unsure of what you mean with authenticator. My code is pretty much the same as in the github repo i linked to earlier..

Comment: Btw one question why u need the Id token

Comment: this might help you maybe :https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/07/31/xamarin-essentials-webauthenticator

Comment: I'm using Realm Sync in a Xamarin Forms application. I need sign in with google, and realm provides that functionality - but to sign the user into the application using realm, i need the id_token and not the access_token which is currently returned